# when is it beneficial to use "JavaScript window resize event with a (..ms) delay"

Tags: javascript, wordpress, resize

The code below uses timers to create a "JavaScript window resize event with a (..ms) delay", in this case, to show and hide menu. The delay, in short, minimizes the machine resources that the resize event might otherwise employ. But, the delay doesn't hide the menu quickly enough and decreasing the delay for the desired effect, seems to defeat the object the delay in the first place.

The function below is within a document ready, anonymous function in Wordpress. Would appreciate opinions on this. Thanks.

```
 var resizeTimer;
    $(window).on('load resize', function () {
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = setTimeout(function () {
            if ($(window).width() > 768) {
                $('ul.menu-1').show();
                $('.toggle').hide();
            } else {
                $('ul.menu-1').hide();
                $('.toggle').show();
            }
        }, 100);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the idea is that when the window resizes, it triggers many times.  So a quick adjustment to a new size can call the code x times when you only really need it to execute once.

But it's a common trap.  Most people who constantly resize windows are developers and designers -- not your average customer/audience.  I don't think removing a delay would impact performance at all (unless you have a resize-maniac dev going to town on the screen).

Plus, all this code could be done without JS -- just using media queries in CSS.

My personal opinion would be ditch the JS resize solution to show/hide a menu and go with a CSS + Media Query solution.  It'll be a lot kinder on your resources and easier to maintain.

Comment: Hi Douglas, That's good to hear, in fact I was hoping for this kind of confirmation , ie.  it is developers who mostly resize etc. On your last comment,  CSS media queries are superseded by the other js slideToggle method in the overall script for mobile 1st on click drop down - hence the use of js hide and show.